# Apps not showing under Cellular Data in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios4

There are plenty of Apps in my iPad. Under "Settings -> Cellular Data", no apps are shown. 
I want the App which is developed by me to be shown under this option. I am using iPad3 with 3G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple,we have to use 3G network instead of wifi for your App atleast once then it will appear in that list.